# 12 inch jpg needs to be one inch but it is getting blurry and pixelated. Why would that happen?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, resize, jpg, blur

Is the size difference just too much? I am resizing on Photoshop and it is not working. My client says that makes no sense and I need to just "do it". I know you can lose quality when making something bigger but I have not heard of losing quality making something smaller.
To be more clear
-12"X12" needed to be sized down to a 1"X1"
-It is a JPG
-I used Photoshop and Illustrator
-its a logo for a soccer ball and they don't have an eps file or ai.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's not really enough information to work out what is going wrong here.  What size is the original image in pixels (width and height)? What size in inches (width and height) do you want to it to be?  Is this for something that is going to be printed?  Are you doing the page layout in Illustrator? Please edit your question and add the missing info. Thanks.

Comment: You've "over tagged" this and made it confusing. Please correct the tags. If Illustrator isn't in use, remove that tag. If it is in use, how?? The reduction **is** considerable in terms of inches, and **interpolation** *does* happen in *Photoshop* with reductions (pixels are discarded) - but *not* in Illustrator. Without more information it's difficult to help.

Comment: Your "edit" provides no additional information... Please read @BillyKerr 's comment above... we *want* to help, unfortunately we can't help you if you don't provide enough information. -- what are the *pixel* dimensions of the image? The PPI ate the original 12"? How are you resizing? In what app specifically - you cant be using both PS and AI at the same time.

Comment: Are you a designer?

Answer (score -1):

in photoshop convert image layer into smart object and scale it. it may help.

Refer Below link.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html